# keycloak 4.8 Rest API

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to retrive the users list of a specific realm.

I've read this documentation [uri schema](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.8/rest-api/index.html#_uri_scheme) [user resource](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.8/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource)

So i've tried the following curl cmd:

```
curl \
  -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: bearer $KC_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/$KC_REALM/users"
```

I got a **404** error.

The user exist in the realm and has the **view-users** role.

This is the docker-compose file that i'm using to test then env ([docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-mysql.yml))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
curl \
  -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: bearer $KC_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/$KC_REALM/users"
```

Comment: Are you sure that Keycloak is published on `localhost` interface?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
curl \
  -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: bearer $KC_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users"
```